# ASP.Net application locks up

Tags: asp.net

FFRS froze reasons

We have ASP.Net 2.0 application. It was running corretly and suddenly get loked up, when I kept opened a member edit page for 20 minutes or so. And after 20 minutes when I cliked on save. It is locked. Not it does not let me login. Niether it opens the login page sometimes.

This has happened twice.

In hosting server architecture we have two app servers and two db servers for fail over purposes.

Your precious help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the session state to save login information you may need to change the life time of the session. by default it is 20 min